# JQuery Validation Globalization MVC 4 DateTime

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, datetime-format, jquery-globalization

In my class I have the property:

```
public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Which renders "31/12/2012 12:00:00 AM" by default with the culture set to "en-CA" and "12/31/2012 12:00:00 AM" if the culture is "en-US".

The JQuery validation works fine in "en-US" but in "en-CA" complains about "The field Date must be a date".

I think the solution is using the JQuery Globalization library. I just don't know how to do it for this ["General Date Long Time ("G") Format Specifier"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#GeneralDateLongTime) ASP.Net renders. Any ideas?

[image: The field Date must be a date]

Comment: How are you setting the culture "en-US", "en-CA"?

Comment: Thanks for the interest @LenielMacaferi. Is in the Web.config `<globalization culture="en-CA" uiCulture="auto" />`.

Answer (score 0):

The [General Long time ("G") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#GeneralDateLongTime) format specifier "represents a combination of the short date ("d") and long time ("T") patterns, separated by a space".

While there is not an equivelant format specifier ([jQuery Globalize Date Formatting](https://github.com/jquery/globalize#date-formatting)) the same format can be accomplished by (verbose for clarity):

```
var shortDate = $.format(@Model.Date, "d");  //Get the short date  ...M/d/yyyy
var longTime = $.format(@Model.Date, "T");  //Get the long time...h:mm:ss tt  
var date = shortDate + " " + longTime;  //concat the two together.
```